# How to remove titlebar in NSWindow using SwiftUI as root view?

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I want be able to remove NSWindow titlebar with the code below. It does the job but there is a gap now. How do I solve this issue?

```
lazy var window: NSWindow = NSWindow()
window.styleMask = [.titled, .fullSizeContentView, .closable]
window.backingType = .buffered
window.backgroundColor = .clear

window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
window.titleVisibility = .hidden

window.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
window.standardWindowButton(NSWindow.ButtonType.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true

window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: TestView())

window.center()
window.setFrameAutosaveName("No Title Bar Window")
window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
```

[image]

PS: I am not looking to modify the SwiftUI view with some modifiers to fill the gap. I'm trying to solve the issue in Cocoa part or NSWindow part rather than in SwiftUI part.

Comment: What if you remove `titled`?

Comment: then I am losing close button also the window lose the corner radius!

Comment: Can you post a better picture? It's nearly completely black and it's not clear what gap you are referring to.